# How do I make Django call a put rather than get request?

Tags: python, django

In the Djano code below how do I make the url(r'^hello-world/$', MyView.as_view(), name='hello_world') call a PUT rather than a GET?

```
url(r'^hello-world/$', MyView.as_view(), name='hello_world'),

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, World")
```

Comment: It's the client that is responsible for making the request, not the server. If the client makes a PUT request, the `put` method will be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to use this url-name in HTML template.

You can't raw `HTML` can only call `GET` or `POST` for **POST** you would have to use form and `method=post` . For any other request you can assign a javascript function call on Button click or hyperlink. From there you can send all type of requests.

If you want to respond to `put` call on that url just add `def put`  in that class

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, World")

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, World")
```